# MySQL group by value and max date

Tags: php, mysql

I need to extract the last character of columns result_1 and result_2 and group them so I have a list from 0 to 9 indicating when it was generated.
In the folowing code I managed to obtain a list from 0 to 9 but the date is the earliest date in the table and not the latest.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ((SELECT RIGHT(result_1, 1) AS results, date 
    FROM act_results ORDER BY date ASC) 
    UNION ALL (SELECT RIGHT(result_2, 1) AS results, date 
    FROM act_results)) s WHERE results != ''";

$sql .= " GROUP BY results";

$table = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($table)) {
   echo $row['results']." (".$row['date'].") <br>";
}
```

Any ideas how to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by` with `max()`:

```
SELECT results, max(date)
FROM ((SELECT RIGHT(result_1, 1) AS results, date
       FROM act_results
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT RIGHT(result_2, 1) AS results, date
       FROM act_results
      )
     ) s
WHERE results <> ''
GROUP BY results;
```